# Cannot get property value with jQuery noConflict

Tags: jquery

I'm a jQuery beginner and I can't figure out why I can't get the property value 
of an object when it runs within the jQuery load method.

Here's a summarised code which show the issue:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

  alert(jQuery('#some-tag').prop('title')); //Display the title value.

  //Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics.
  jQuery(window).load(function() {
    alert(jQuery('#some-tag').prop('title'));  //Display nothing (???)

  });
```

It works when noConflict is not involved, though.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: why  you are using `jquery.noconflict()`

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle using ur version of jquery ?

Comment: I use jquery noconflict to avoid problems with mootools library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics.
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    alert(jQuery('#some-tag').prop('title'));  //Display nothing (???)

 });
```

Comment: well i think when window load it should work too..??? what is the different in OP code and Your code.

Comment: The document ready event executes already when the HTML-Document is loaded and the DOM is ready, even if all the graphics haven’t loaded yet. 

The window load event executes a bit later when the complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response but it still doesn't work.
another suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Both versions work in my JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2u34/1/

```
jQuery.noConflict();

  alert(jQuery('#some-tag').prop('title')); //Display the title value.

  //Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics.
  jQuery(window).load(function() {
    alert(jQuery('#some-tag').prop('title'));  //Display nothing (???)

});
```

The code section was placed somewhere at the bottom of the body section.

**Edit:**

Just another guess - since the issue only exists, when `.noConflict()` is involved: Could it be that somewhere on your page there is a (hidden) jQuery-call, using the `$` syntax that cannot be executed in `noConflict` mode?

Comment: Indeed it works... odd !
I use 1.10.2 version, could it be the pb ?

Comment: Well I think it's something about the tag.
I tried with the simple span tag you've suggest in JSfiddle and it works.
The tag I try to work with is a label tag into a form (Joomla). 
So I guess I have to search further for the key of the issue.

Comment: It does work just the same with a `<label>` tag, see here http://jsfiddle.net/Z2u34/3/ ...

Comment: After some tests it turns out that the issue occurs only with html tags generated with PHP.
Everything does work with hard coded tags.

Any tip to work around the problem ?

Comment: Have a look at the page source code as it appears in your browser (cntrl u). Do you see any differences between the 'hard coded' and the 'PHP-generated' tags? This is essentially what jQuery will work on ...

Comment: They all look like regular html tags.
Here's a snippet:

`<ul class="adminformlist"> 
<li><label id="jform_name-lbl" for="jform_name" class="hasTip required" title="Name::Name of the element">Nom<span class="star">&#160;*</span></label>  <input type="text" name="jform[name]" id="jform_name" value="" class="required" size="25"/></li>`


ul and li tags are hard coded, and label and input tags are generated by PHP.
Do you see any difference ?

Comment: Have you made sure that the `id` tags are all *unique*? I. e. is there only **one** `id="jform_name-lbl"` on the whole page? This is important if you are actually addressing the label through an `id` tag.

Comment: Yes, I've checked and there are all unique. The thing is why the first alert() works correctly and the second doesn't ?
Is the window object modify the jQuery behavior ?